# Data binding in Spring MVC with GET requests

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a very mind bothering question on Spring MVC.

Think that I have a controller with method responds to GET requests and a JSP form.

Now while the form is partially filled, I send a GET request to the controller.

Question is, would that partially filled data be available in the backing object, at the method responding to GET requests ?

Comment: did you actually try this out? I think you will get the answer if you try once.

Comment: Why not try a get on bean attributes inside the GET method? AFAIK spring doesn't care partially filled/full filled form (unless you have validations mapped).